# master data services url

Tags: silverlight, url, master-data-services

I've included the Master Data Services Silverlight frontend in SharePoint using an iframe. I wan't to link to specific entities and such in this frontend. I know I can link directly to entities, and even filter on specific parameters using the EID and MECD queryparameter i.e.:

```
XXX/Explorer/AttributeSL.aspx?MID=2&amp;VID=2&amp;EID=11&amp;AID=208&amp;MECD=31220&amp;hosted=true#/ExplorerEntity?MID=2&amp;VID=2&amp;EID=11&amp;AID=208&amp;MECD=31220&amp;hosted=true
```

What I would like to do is to link to a hierarchy, and automatically select a specific node in that hierarchy. Is that possible?

The link to the hierarchy is:

```
XXX/Explorer/ExplorerDerivedHierarchy.aspx?HTID=1&HID=1&MID=2&VID=2#/ExplorerDerivedHierarchy?HTID=1&HID=1&MID=2&VID=2
```

But it always selects the "root" node automatically.

Thanks